# WYSIWYG - Output Word Like Pages & Pagination - Split Content

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I am trying to get to split HTML content into pages, so I can make a web page present in word-like interface.

A user will use a WYSIWYG editor to create content and the content is added in the "document-wrapper" element. The plan is that a user can add a "page"/"page-break" to break the content into separate pages and end up with an HTML structure like so:

```
<div class="document-wrapper">
   <div class="document-page">Page 1</div>
   <div class="document-page">Page 2</div>
</div>
```

So, instead of generating something like this:
[Content with page break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTxCp.png)

I want to generate something more like that:
[Multi-page layout document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TJIA.png)

My questions are:

1. How can I ensure that a div that represents a page has a set height and width in all devices & screen densities?
2. What's the most efficient way of ensuring that content inputted dynamically by a user will overflow to a next sibling div page element, and if one doesn't exist, then create one?